IdentityServer4 CORS is giving error in . well-known/openid-configuration
We have the following configuration in our application but while authentication its giving us this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Error parsing discovery document from https://identity.benchmarkportal-ct.solventum.be: Error connecting to https://identity.benchmarkportal-ct.solventum.be/.well-known/openid-configuration. The SSL connection could not be established, 

startup.cs
protected override IServiceCollection ConfigureCustomServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   return base.ConfigureCustomServices(services)
         .AddCors(options =>
         {
             options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigins",
                 builder =>
                 {
                     builder
                         .WithOrigins(AppSettings.IdentityEndpoint, AppSettings.PrimaryEndpoint)
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod();
                 });
         })
         .AddIdentityServer(options =>
     {
         options.Cors.CorsPolicyName = "AllowSpecificOrigins";
         options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
         options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
         options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
         options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
     })
    }

startup.cs
protected override IApplicationBuilder ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    .UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins")
    .UseIdentityServer()
}


The error looks not like a CORS problem, but instead a HTTPS issue, that the client can't reach it over HTTPS... are both services on the same network? behind a router?
